# Ionic 2 slides autoplay

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic2.

Here is my template

```
<ion-slides autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="500" pager="true">

    <ion-slide   class="slider1">
            <h1>My <span>Neighbours</span></h1>
            <p>My Neighbours is a directory of people who live in the building and have chosen to</p>

            <div class="homepeople">
                <div class="home"></div>
                <div class="people"></div>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>

        <ion-slide class="slider2">
            <h1>CCTV <span>Monitoring</span></h1>
            <p>Residents/Managers can view selected CCTV</p>
            <div class="iconholder">
                <img src="./assets/images/white CCTV Monitoring.svg" alt="Image">
            </div>
        </ion-slide>

        <ion-slide class="slider3">
            <h1>Emergency</h1>
            <p>Security / Reception / Police / Ambulance / Fire</p>
            <div class="iconholder">
                <div class="iconholder-blk">
                   <img src="./assets/images/white emergency icon.svg" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="iconholder-blk">
                    <img src="./assets/images/white Alarm.svg" alt="Image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button ion-button outline small (click)="navHome()">
                Start using the app
            </button>
        </ion-slide>  
 </ion-slides>
```

It's work perfect.But i need loop does not continue on when last slide.

How can i do this.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: have you tried setting loop to false

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Ya i set loop to false.again go to first slider after does not autoplay.

Comment: Will you always have 3 slides

Comment: Ya.Can u help me

Comment: Let me get coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So i used some of the helper functions on the [ionic 2 documentation for sildes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/).

The `(ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()"` handles the slides autoplay, so when the slide reaches 3 which is your maximum, i stop the autoplay using `this.slides.stopAutoplay();`.

The **html** is as:-

```
<ion-slides autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="500" pager="true" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">

    <ion-slide   class="slider1">
      <h1>My <span>Neighbours</span></h1>
      <p>My Neighbours is a directory of people who live in the building and have chosen to</p>

      <div class="homepeople">
        <div class="home"></div>
        <div class="people"></div>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide class="slider2">
      <h1>CCTV <span>Monitoring</span></h1>
      <p>Residents/Managers can view selected CCTV</p>
      <div class="iconholder">
        <img src="./assets/images/white CCTV Monitoring.svg" alt="Image">
      </div>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide class="slider3">
      <h1>Emergency</h1>
      <p>Security / Reception / Police / Ambulance / Fire</p>
      <div class="iconholder">
        <div class="iconholder-blk">
          <img src="./assets/images/white emergency icon.svg" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="iconholder-blk">
          <img src="./assets/images/white Alarm.svg" alt="Image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button ion-button outline small (click)="navHome()">
        Start using the app
      </button>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

The **ts** is as:-

```
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
  constructor() {
  }
  slideChanged() {
    let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
    if(currentIndex==3){
      this.slides.stopAutoplay();
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a configuration for an Ionic Slide

**Complete Source**: [**Link**](http://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-multiple-slides-on-single-view-using-swiper-slider/)
[image]

**HTML**

```
    <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOptsOne" #slideWithNav
      (ionSlideDidChange)="SlideDidChange(sliderOne,slideWithNav)">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let s of sliderOne.slidesItems">
        <img src="../../assets/images/{{s.id}}.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

**Component**

With **AutoPlay** Set to true

```
slideOptsOne = {
  initialSlide: 0,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  autoplay:true
};
```